# Complexity of inefficient divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, divide-and-conquer

An instance of size `n` is divided into `p≥2` instances each of size `n-a` where `a` is a small `integer` and `p` is a `constant`. The computation cost of this operation (i.e. dividing into instances) is a unit, with `C(0)=1.`

I am trying to find the complexity of this design.  I am having trouble putting the words into an equation, here is what I think the recursion should look like:

```
C(n) = (n-a)*C(n/p) + 1
```

is this correct?

Comment: No it's not. Read the problem one more time and identify the number of subproblems created and the size of each subproblem. Currently, those are wrong in the equation.

Comment: Remember that the formula is: C(size) = (number of subproblems)*C(size of subproblem) + (cost of dividing). You know it all, just interpret the formula correctly. I won't answer the question directly, I expect you to do so.

Comment: Also know that if no one answers, and you *do* figure it out, you are able to answer your own question.  If you do that, be sure to provide a solid explanation along with your answer.

Comment: I am downvoting the question since I believe that SO is not a place for homework help. It doesn't add anything useful to the SO archive: nobody would ever search for an "inefficient divide and conquer algorithm", and the example is highly simplistic and artificial to be of any help for working programmers. It also takes other people's time while you are not learning as much as you would otherwise. (I know we all have our particular circumstances, sometimes very difficult, but nevertheless this is my opinion.)

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy this is one of two cases when a divide and conquer algorithm should be avoided... as a programmer it's important to know when to write iterative or recursive code i think.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be something like this:

```
C(n) = (p)*C(n-a) + 1
```

My rationale is that you said 'p≥2 instances each of size n-a' in your question. Thus the size reduces to `C(n-a)` and there are p subproblems. So I think it would be something like `p*C(n-a)`. You got the other term right. The cost of dividing at each step is `C(0) = 1` as you said.

Comment: hmmm... this is what I think now too but would this be complexity exponential in n... going to keep trying this.

Comment: Well you did mention the word "inefficient" in your title. Maybe that is the whole point of this problem, to show that a nearly exponential time complexity is possible with Divide and Conquer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this looks like a school assignment, particularly because of the wording "inefficient divide and conquer algorithm", I won't answer it directly either.

My advice would be to use `a=1` and `p=2` as an example. In this case you have to solve two subproblems of size `n-1`, and then spend 1 unit of time to combine the solutions. If it takes you 1 unit of time to solve for `n=1`, i.e. `C(1)=1`, then you get

```
C(1)=1
C(2) = 2*C(1) + 1 = 3
C(3) = 2*C(2) + 1 = 7
C(4) = 2*C(3) + 1 = 15
```

etc. So you get `C(n) =2^n - 1`. If `a` is not 1, this is basically the same thing: you'd just raise to the power `n/a` instead of `n`.

By the way, isn't it peculiar that you call `a` a "small integer", whereas `p` is "a constant"? Of course, both expressions mean the same thing. All constants are "small", as far as asymptotic behavior is concerned.

Comment: i agree the wording is a bit odd... I ended up finding the complexity to be C(n) = p^(n/a) + [(p^(n/a) - 1) / (p - 1)] which would be big O(p^n) which is exponential.

Answer (score 0):

As Shashank wrote C(n) = p⋅C(n-a) + 1 is correct.

I just want to mention that this results in

> C(n) = Σ<sub>i=0,...,n/a</sub> p<sup>i</sup> = p<sup>n/a + 1</sup> - 1

So C(n) is in O(p<sup>n/a</sup>), which is exponential in n.